# Square payment gateway in e-commerce site

Tags: woocommerce, e-commerce, payment-gateway, square

Issue is I have applied Square payment gateway and added all require details in WordPress, but I can't get PIN code and CVC number fields while payment for product.
Also have tried with using Sandbox too, but still facing same issue.

I have tried with client's actual APIs and also from my personal account too, but facing same issue.